# Slipt in python superfluous one character " "

Tags: python

I'm newer to Python and  When I use .slipt() superfluous one character

```
txt = "8/"

x = txt.split("/")

print(x)
```

result is:

```
['8', '']
```

but I want the result is:

```
['8']
```

how to fix it

Comment: I think it is the same but I just get index = 0 so this very long @fen1x

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers in question that I mentioned - try `print(list(filter(None, x)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this because `.slipt()` Method split a string into a list. Using /, as a separator, split a string into a list with the respect to "/".
In the asked question:

```
txt = "8/"

x = txt.split("/")

print(x)
```

You are split the string with respect to "/". You can visualize `txt = "8/"` as `txt = "8"+"/"+""`.
If you want your output to do this `['8']`. You can use `x.remove("")` to remove `""`
so the Final Code is:

```
txt = "8"+"/"+""

x = txt.split("/")
x.remove("")

print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a solution specifically and this help me

Answer (score 0):

Just use list slicing:

```
x = txt.split("/")[0]
```

Prints:

```
8
```

But convert it to a list again:

```
x = list(txt.split("/")[0])
```

Prints:

```
['8']
```

Since your list contains *two* values, use indexing - `[0]` to get the *first* at the zeroth index.

##### See also

[Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: Oh it works but when indexing +1 like "8/9/" it not feasibility

Answer (score 0):

```
x = list(txt.split("/")[0])
```

or

```
x = list(txt.split("/")[-2])
```

[Slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip and then split. Strip remove the character in front or back to avoid empty strings

**Code:**

```
txt = "8/"
x = txt.strip("/").split("/")
print(x)
```

It also works if there is leading / in the string.

**Code:**

```
txt = "/8/"
x = txt.strip("/").split("/")
print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
['8']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "8/"

#Create a list of words from the text
words = text.split("/")

# Remove any empty elements from the list
filtered_list = [word for word in words if word.strip()]

print(filtered_list)
```

**Output**: ['8']